# Split text file into lines by key word python

Tags: python, file, text, line, txt

I have a large text file I have imported in python and want to split into lines by a key word, then use those lines to take out relevent information into a dataframe.

The data follows along the same pattern for each line but wont be the exact same number of characters and some lines may have extra data

So I have a text file such as:

{data: name:Mary, friends:2, cookies:10, chairs:4},{data: name:Gerald friends:2, cookies:10, chairs:4, outside:4},{data: name:Tom, friends:2, cookies:10, chairs:4, stools:1}

There is always the key word **data** between lines, is there any way I can split it out by using this word as the beginning of the line (then put it into a dataframe)?

I'm not sure where to begin so any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the content of a `.txt` file like this...

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

...you have it as a `str`ing, so you can split it with the function `str.split()`:

```
content = content.split(my_keyword)
```

---

You can do it with a function:

```
def splitter(path: str, keyword: str) -> str:
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
return content.split(keyword)
```

that you can call this way:

```
>>> splitter("file.txt", "data")
["I really like to write the word ", ", because I think it has a lot of meaning."]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you!  Once I've done that, how would I got about extracting the information? into a dataframe? So I want to have a column with name where I can extract the name, so each line of text becomes a row in the dataframe effectively

Comment: @Harlot_Quinn, I would suggest to search on google something like "Python list into rows pandas dataframe" or something like that.